# I can not build my project on Android Studio because JCenter is crashing:

Tags: android, android-studio, jcenter

I can not build my project on Android Studio because this problem:

```
Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/room/room-common/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

I clicked in the link below and is showing me this error:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 1):

There is an outage with Jcenter.

Please subscribe to https://status.bintray.com/ for further updates.

Comment: Great! thank you!

I just subscribe me in Bintray.

Answer (score 0):

JCenter is crashing:
[image]

JCenter should solve this problem.

Comment: Apparently, the issue was identified and fixed.
https://status.bintray.com/incidents/352gm8426gcg